# Emailing a form with PHP and HTML error message "Cannot POST mail.php"

Tags: php, html, css, forms, email

Second time I've posted about this website I'm coding but I'm making good progress! I'm trying to set up a form that when the user fills out will send to my email - not too difficult right? Well when I eventually hit the submit button, I get the error:

> Cannot POST /mail.php

This is the HTML for the form that I've got:

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><a href="" class="button submit">Send Message</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And this is my mail.php file

```
<?php
$myemail = "MYEMAIL";
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
$message = "

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit();

function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Both files are in the same directory so I have no idea why this isn't working :( Thanks guys <3

Edit: This is what the form looks [like](https://gyazo.com/fe3fef7d1db9802aaa6a68e88b9afecf)

Edit 2: Changed button to:

```
<li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="button submit" /></li>
```

but still getting same problem :/

Edit 3: Can also confirm that

```
<li><button type="submit" value="Send Message" class="button submit" /></li>
```

doesn't make a difference :((

Comment: you need an input having "submit" as type to submit the form , you can not do it with a <a> tag

Comment: @PacMan If that's an answer, please create one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a button for that

`<button class="yourclasshere" type="submit" name="sendMail">Send Mail</button>`

In your PHP you'll need to add a line of code that checks to see if the form is being submitted. This can be accomplished with the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendMail'])) {
    //validate your inputs and submit the form here
}
```

What this does is checks to see if you've clicked the submit button (in this example you're going by the name of the button which I've named 'sendMail') and if you have, you can set the values of your other variables (name, email, message) using your existing function.

From there if everything is good, you should be able to send your mail.